# Maven release plugin - pom.xml update via service account

Tags: java, maven, devops

I am trying to do Continuous integration

1. Created stage checkout
2. created stage build sh "mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean deploy -Dusername=${username} -Dpassword=${password}"
3. Created stage release sh "mvn release:prepare release:perform -Dusername=${username} -Dpassword=${password}" -Dscmusername${username} -Dscmpassword=${password}"
4. At release stage I am reading the version from pom.xml to append in the path of generated artefacts at artifactory.
5. I need to place the jars in the path where the version number is mentioned in the path as a folder – eg dev/version/modules/jar
6. Here the pom.xml gets updated via a service account while performing maven release- Is there a way that I get the right version to be appended in the folder path of artifactory without doing any commits to pom.xml via service account

Comment: Reading the version from the pom file and adding it to the path of generated artifacts does not make sense cause an artifact is identified by it's coordinates groupId/artifactId/version. Why do you need 5. ? And what is the intention of that?

Comment: 5 is just making CD job a little more easier and artefacts are arranged rightly. artifact is identified by it's coordinates groupId/artifactId/version ---I agree with this point but how do I bump upp the pom.xml without making service accounts to commit to stash

Comment: Artifacts are arranged by coordinates there is no need to do it manually or different. To change a version in a more dynamic way: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html apart from that username/password etc. should be configured in `settings.xml` which should be handled by your ci solution.

Comment: Apart from that a change in version is a change in the `pom.xml` which should be recorded in version control or even creating a release (maybe the release should be signed)